# PHP Regular expression finding a string until

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a url grabber setup and it was working fine. It grabs the url of a doc that is in a response header such as:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
document.location.href = 'http\x3a\x2f\x2fcms.example.com\x2fd\x2fd\x2fworkspace\x2fSpacesStore\x2f61d96949-b8fb-43f1-adaf-0233368984e0\x2fFinancial\x2520Agility\x2520Report.pdf\x3fguest\x3dtrue'
</script>
```

Here is my grabber script.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$target_url = $_POST['to'];
$html =file_get_contents($target_url);

$pattern = "/document.location.href = '([^']*)'/";
preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

$raw_url = $matches[1][0];
$eval_url = '$url = "'.$raw_url.'";';

eval($eval_url);
echo $url;
```

We had to add a variable to our doc management system so each doc url needed ?guest=true on the end of the url. When we did this my grabber returned the full url and appends that to the filename. So I tried to have it grab just the url until it hit /guest=true. With this code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$target_url = $_POST['to'];
$html =file_get_contents($target_url);

$pattern = "/document.location.href = '([^']*)\x3fguest\x3dtrue'/";

preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

$raw_url = $matches[1][0];
$eval_url = '$url = "'.$raw_url.'";';

eval($eval_url);
echo $url;
```

Why isn't it returning the url up until the ?guest=true part? aka why doesn't this work? and what's the fix?

Comment: Why do you try to match `?` and `=`, when the original string has `\x3f` and `\x3d`? It's eval that turns the latter into the former.

Comment: @raina77ow yes I tried matching exactly and this copy and paste was from a frustration attempt. Neither works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution. You'll get the match directly, not in group.

```
set_time_limit(0);

$target_url = $_POST['to'];
$html = file_get_contents($target_url);

$pattern = '/(?<=document\.location\.href = \').*?(?=\\\\x3fguest\\\\x3dtrue)/';

preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches))

$raw_url = $matches[0];
$eval_url = '$url = "'.$raw_url.'";';

eval($eval_url);
echo $url;
```

You can check out the results **[here](http://regexr.com?323rb)**.

The problem with your regex was in the fact that you did not escape certain characters in the string (`.` and `\`) that you wanted to catch literary. Furthermore, you do not need to use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` and offset of `3`. I guess you copied these values from the example on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Here's an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
# (?<=document\.location\.href = ').*?(?=\\x3fguest\\x3dtrue)
# 
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=document\.location\.href = ')»
#    Match the characters “document” literally «document»
#    Match the character “.” literally «\.»
#    Match the characters “location” literally «location»
#    Match the character “.” literally «\.»
#    Match the characters “href = '” literally «href = '»
# Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\\x3fguest\\x3dtrue')»
#    Match the character “\” literally «\\»
#    Match the characters “x3fguest” literally «x3fguest»
#    Match the character “\” literally «\\»
#    Match the characters “x3dtrue” literally «x3dtrue»
```

*This answer has been edited to reflect updates to the question.*

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I pasted the wrong code and am trying to match \x3fguest\x3dtrue not ?guest=true. Using that in your code did not give me the results I was looking for

Comment: @McPace I have updated the answer, please let me know if it now works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your regex is wrong. You added `\?guest=true` to your regex, which matches `?guest=true` literally.

In your example response header, it ends with `\x3fguest\x3dtrue`, which is different.

Try:

```
$pattern="/document.location.href = '([^']*)(\?|(\\x3f))guest(=|(\\x3d))true'/";
```

I simply replaced the following sub-expressions:

- `\?` is now `(\?|(\\x3f))` which matches `?` or `\x3f` literally
- `=`  is now `(=|(\\x3d))` which matches `=` or `\x3d` literally

That way, if the escaped hexadecimal representation of `?` or `=` is used, it will still match correctly.

Comment: Thanks ronalchn, this seems like it would work but it isn't. This would alter my matches results correct? Would I need to use something other than matches[1][0]?